# Why is it that when I do hasAttribute() and the element has the attribute, it returns false?

Tags: javascript

I am making a custom elements program which creates a countdown. I have 2 custom attributes that I am using - "ed" and "cd-type".

I have tried sending it through JavaScript validators and fixing some errors. I have also tried declaring a variable with the value of "this" inside the constructor.

```
class SCWCountdown extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    if (this.hasAttribute("ed")) {
      b = new Date(this.getAttribute("ed")).getTime() + new Date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    } else {
      b = new Date("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z").getTime() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    }
    if (this.hasAttribute("cd-type")) {
      c = this.getAttribute("cd-type");
    } else {
      c = "dt";
    }
```

The code above, for BOTH conditionals, uses the function from the "else" conditional. I have tried doing

```
console.log(this.hasAttribute("cd-type"));
console.log(this.hasAttribute("ed"));
```

They BOTH returned false. This is the code in my html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--The script with the custom elements-->
<script src="custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<scw-countdown ed="2040-01-01T00:00:00Z" cd-type="uf"></scw-countdown>
```

Link to my full custom elements script: https://www.scwc.cf/custom.js

Link to the countdown: https://www.scwc.cf/custom-test.html

Comment: I'm guessing the DOM doesn't like or recognize your custom `scw-countdown` element.

Comment: Does your `this` actually has attribute `ed`? Maybe it points to something else?

Comment: im test it in console chrome and it work, inside the first if return this error `VM33:7 Uncaught TypeError: Date.getTimezoneOffset is not a constructor` I think because date need `()`,   ` Date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me (except some syntax error regarding Date: `TypeError: Date.getTimezoneOffset is not a constructor`). Here's a minimum example:

```js
  class SCWCountdown extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      let c;
      if (this.hasAttribute("cd-type")) {
        c = this.getAttribute("cd-type");
      } else {
        c = "dt";
      }
      
      console.log(c);
    }
  }

  window.customElements.define("scw-countdown", SCWCountdown);
```

```html
<body>
  <scw-countdown cd-type="uf"></scw-countdown>
</body>
```

Another thing to note, if you put the `console.log`s before the `customElements.define` call, then `cd-type` and `ed` will still be undefined because the `SCWCountdown` constructor will not have been called yet.

Comment: It's better suited to be comment, not an answer

Comment: how would u provide a minimum example as a comment?

Comment: Ah - looks like this person forgot to define their custom element, thus the line `window.customElements.define("scw-countdown", SCWCountdown);`

Comment: @MaxVoisard Have you seen full example? It is defined an the end

Comment: @Justinas Oh my bad I didn't know it was there.